# JavaML - How to add separators when exporting data as CSV?

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to generate random instances to create a dataset.I try creating it with the next code:

```
....
Instance tmpInstance = InstanceTools.randomInstance(4);
data.add(tmpInstance);
....
```

If I print it in the system.out:

```
[{[0.9539317274046737, 0.7367254963392549, 0.9265618402925881, 0.6691294511669751];null}]
```

But when I save it to a file, the numbers aren't separated by anything, they are all the numbers together.

```
net.sf.javaml.tools.data.FileHandler.exportDataset(data, new File("C:/Users/agomez/Desktop/data.csv"));
```

How can I separate them?

Comment: What is this `InstanceTools`, could you provide full package name?

Comment: @oleg.cherednik this is the instanceTools I am using: `net.sf.javaml.tools.InstanceTools` Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javaml Filehandler you use does not provide that option. It is specified here:

http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/api/0.1.5/net/sf/javaml/tools/data/FileHandler.html

If you need CSV output, follow questions like these:

- [Creating csv file using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529749/creating-csv-file-using-java/15530115#15530115)
- [Writing to a csv file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145933/writing-to-a-csv-file-in-java)

Basically commons-csv or opencsv. But if it's really only numbers, you can probably write your java code.

Comment: And what library I could use to create dataset that allows comma separated values?